# Creating CI/CD heroku , git and jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github, heroku, jenkins-plugins

I am creating continous intergration with jekins , git and heroku

I have followed instruction from [Setting up Jekins to deploy to heroku](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-up-jenkins-to-deploy-to-heroku)

when I add heroku repository I get the following error

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h https://git.heroku.com/angular.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: !   WARNING:
remote: !   Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !   Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
remote: !   See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/angular.git/'
```

Here is visual of the error in jekins
[image]

I am getting the error only by entering the link of heroku repository  without even entering any credentials.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorials shows the same screen, but with credentials:

[image: https://lankydanblog.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/jenkins-image-71.png?w=1024]

I understand entering the URL alone will trigger the error message, but you should be able to then select your pre-recorded credentials, making that message disappear.

Comment: Hii.  I am new to this  stuff I am ble to enter git hub credentials but when I add new repository for heroku and try to click add nothing is triggered, am stuck and I dont know what to do , online tutorials nothing works :(

Comment: @Kaczkapojebana you would need to declare an heroku login in your Jenkins Credentials before being able to use it in the screen shown above.